# Why does Python add tuples as vectors inside of a list comprehension but concatenates them with the '+' operator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, vector, tuples, list-comprehension

Consider the following code:

```
def vector_add(v, w):
    """adds corresponding elements"""
    return [v_i + w_i
            for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w)]

def main():
    pair_1 = (1, 2)
    pair_2 = (2, 3)

    sum = pair_1 + pair_2
    print(sum)

    print vector_add(pair_1, pair_2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It prints the following:

```
(1, 2, 2, 3)
[3, 5]
```

Why did the `+` operator perform a concatenation while the list comprehension added the tuples like vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not adding tuples in the list comprehension, but integers.

`zip` returns a tuple of two ints which are *unpacked* into `v_i` and `w_i`. The `+` operator is therefore acting on numeric types not tuples.

This is more obvious if you use a for loop and print the values:

```
for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w):
    print v_i, w_i
# 1 2
# 2 3
```

In the other case, you have a plain old tuple concatenation. Apparently, no surprises.